# Why recycler view is loading till page 3 only?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, rss, rss-reader

Hii i'm working on a project in which I have taken rss feeds from a website and embedded the data into recycler view. The recycler view is working fine till page 3 but on page 4 it doesn't loads...
I have attached the code below. Is there anyone who can help me solving the issue??
You can check out the video here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JxUVgfBfcZR_6eThFNZ2nenEIz3UykCm/view?usp=sharing

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.myapplication.Adapter.FeedAdapter;
import com.example.myapplication.Common.HTTPDataHandler;
import com.example.myapplication.Model.RSSObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RSSObject.RssObject rssObject;
private String rss_link="http://www.freejobalert.com/feed/";
int pageCount = 1;
private final String rss_to_json_api = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    loadRss();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_refresh)
    {
        loadRss();
        pageCount=1;
    }
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.next)
    {

            rss_link+="?paged=";
            pageCount++;
            rss_link+=pageCount;
            loadRss();
    }

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.previous)
    {
        if(pageCount>2)
        {

        rss_link+="?paged=";
        pageCount--;
        rss_link+=pageCount;
        loadRss();}
        else{
            loadRss();
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private void loadRss() {
    AsyncTask<String, String, String> loadRssAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String result;
            HTTPDataHandler httpDataHandler = new HTTPDataHandler();
            result = httpDataHandler.getHTTPData(strings[0]);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            rssObject = new Gson().fromJson(s, RSSObject.RssObject.class);
            FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(rssObject, getBaseContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    };

    StringBuilder url_get_data = new StringBuilder(rss_to_json_api);
    Log.e("Test",""+ rss_link);
    url_get_data.append(rss_link);

    loadRssAsync.execute(url_get_data.toString());
    rss_link="http://www.freejobalert.com/feed/";


}
}
```

Comment: Try logging (s) in onPostExcute and see what is being returned when you reach 4.

Comment: I have solved the issue ...Thanks!